# Suppose p : G → GL(n, C) is a representation. Suppose that g, h exist in G and that p(g)p(h) = p(h)p(g). Is it then true that gh = hg?

Tags: representation-theory

**Suppose $p : G → GL(n, C)$ is a representation. Suppose that $g, h$ exist in $G$ and that $p(g)p(h) = p(h)p(g)$. Is it then true  that $gh = hg$?**

I don't know if I am not understanding the question, but isn't it only true that $p(g)p(h)=p(h)p(g)$ when G is abelian, so in that case $gh=hg$ by definition?

Also a further part of the question is; **does it make a difference if $p$ is faithful?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In general it is not true. Suppose $G$ is not abelian, pick $g$ and $h$ such that $gh \neq hg$. Then take the trivial representation sending everything to the identity matrix. Thanf $\rho \left( g \right) \rho \left( h \right) = \rho \left( h \right) \rho \left( g \right)$ but $h$ and $g$ do not commute.

On the other hand, in case the representation is faithful, the statement is true, since the image is isomorphic to the group $G$.

Comment: oh i see, so p(g)p(h)=p(h)p(g) works when G isn't abelian too? how would i start writing is as more of a "proof"?

Comment: Would it be enough to say;
We choose g,h in G such that gh≠hg. Let p: G->GL(1,C), g->(1) be the trivial representation.
Thus we obtain p(g)p(h)=1, p(h)p(g)=1, hence p(g)p(h)=p(h)p(g), however we have chosen g,h in G such that gh≠hg, therefore we can conclude that it does not always follow that if p(h)p(g)=p(g)p(h) then gh=hg.
?

Comment: If you have an homomorphism of groups $f:G \rightarrow H$ you simply know $f\left(g_{1}g_{2}\right)=f\left(g_{1}\right)f\left(g_{2}\right)$. If you have $f\left(g_{1}g_{2}\right)=f\left(g_{2}g_{1}\right)$, what you can get is $f\left(g_{1}g_{2}g_{1}^{-1}g_{2}^{-1}\right)=e$, nothing more. As you did, since the fact does not hold in general, you can exhibit a counterexample. And your way is ok for this.

Comment: could you please explain in a bit more detail why its true if the representation is faithful, thanks

Comment: A representation is said to be faithful if $\rho$ is injective. Hence by isomorphism theorem for groups, since the kernel is trivial, $G$ is isomorphic to its image under $\rho$. It means that the two groups are "the same", i.e. their structure as groups is the same. If you are not familiar with this, you can invert $\rho$ on its image. You can check is remains an homomorphism. You have $\rho \left(gh\right) = \rho \left( hg \right)$, applying $\rho^{-1}$ both sides (here you use it is faithful, i.e. that you can invert it), you get $gh=hg$.

Comment: So could I just say;
Let p be a faithful representation with map p: G->GL(n,C), g-> p(g) for all g in G. 
Because p is faithful there exists p$^{-1}$:GL(n,C)->G, p(g)->g for all g in G, hence we can apply this to p(gh)=p(hg) to obtain gh=hg

Comment: Well, $\rho^{-1}$ is defined just on $\rho \left( G \right)$. If you correct it, the rest is ok.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: In general, if you have an injective map (even just of sets) $f:A \rightarrow B$, you get uniquely an inverse map $f^{-1}$ defined on $f\left(A\right)$, not from all $B$. Of course, if we are dealing just with sets you can extend it to a map $g:B \rightarrow A$ s.t. $g \circ f = id_{A}$. With groups you can not in general: suppose $2: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ mapping $m \mapsto 2m$. Then you can invert it on $2\mathbb{Z}$, which is the image, but there is no homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2 \mapsto 1$. That's why $\rho^{-1}$ does not extend in general

Comment: oh so p$^{-1}$:p(g)->g for all g in p(g)?

Comment: $\rho^{-1} : \rho \left(G\right) \rightarrow G$ and is s.t. $\rho \left( g \right) \mapsto g$.

Comment: okay i get it thanks!